# Export android application occasionally packages the classes incorrectly

Tags: android, eclipse, adt, eclipse-adt

From Eclipse I righ cick the project, export the Android application and sign with a self generated keystore.

1. After export, occasionally I observe the APK file size is lesser than what I get normally.
2. When the APK file size is incorrect I encounter CNF exception for my application class i.e. DataSystem.
3. I extracted both correct & incorrect APKs.
4. With the help of dex2jar utility I converted the classes.dex to classes_dex2jar.jar and opened in java decompiler (jdgui).
5. I observe parent is clubbed with one of the child package and hence the other child classes of the parent does not exists.

[image]

Due to an incorrect packaging I face ClassNotFoundException on the launch of application.

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate application
>   com.tsf.esharp.DataSystem: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
>   com.tsf.esharp.DataSystem at
>   android.app.LoadedApk.makeApplication(LoadedApk.java:482) at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:3952)
>   at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1300(ActivityThread.java:128) at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1199)
>   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) at
>   android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137) at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4514) at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511) at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:790)
>   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:557) at
>   dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) Caused by:
>   java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.tsf.esharp.DataSystem at
>   dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:61)
>   at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:501) at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:461) at
>   android.app.Instrumentation.newApplication(Instrumentation.java:946)
>   at android.app.LoadedApk.makeApplication(LoadedApk.java:477) ... 11
>   more Force finishing activity
>   com.tsf.esharp.ui.activity/.LauncherActivity

As a precautionary measure, at the time of build I always observe the size of the APK if it is not normal I re-build it. But as my application is in development phase, the components are added/removed quite frequently and hence I do not have a fixed standard size to compare against, so to use this precaution is not practically possible always.

Is this a bug with ADT plugin? Please note, I am using latest revision i.e. 21.1.

Any help would be really appreciated.